# If cell is "text" replace information in 3 cells with information from "data sheet"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m trying to make a formula that automatically replaces 3 cells with information if the text is true.

So basically I have:

**INDEX:** 
A1 (DATE)
B1 (SPESEFIC NUMBER, ex. be2993)
C1 (text)
D2 (text)
D3 (TIME)

**DATA:**
A1 ex. Be2991,A2 ex. Be2992,A3 ex. Be2993,A4 ex. Be2994,A5 ex. Be2995

B1 (text), B2 (text), B3 (text), B4 (text), B5 (text)

C1 (text), C2 (text), C3 (text), C4 (text), C5 (text).

D1 (TIME), D2 (TIME), D3 (TIME), D4 (TIME), D5 (TIME).

What I want to do, is to select ex. be2993 and then the formula copies information from "data" on to the 3 different cells in INDEX file that maches the Be2993 in DATA file

Update:
This is what my Index looks like.

```
    DATO   CNUMBER  ORG DEST    STD ATD
13.01.2014  BA2325  ENZ EMA 20:15   20:18
13.01.2014  BA2324  ENZ LEJ 19:25   19:25
13.01.2014  BA2326  ENZ BGO 8:00    7:53
13.01.2014  BA2327  ENZ OSL 6:05    6:05
```

So here if i put in one of the "cnumber`s" the ORG, DEST and STD will automaitcly be inserted to the cells.  the ATD is manualy putt inn (STD = Standard time of departure, ATD = Actual time of departure).

In the data file it lokks like this:

```
CNUMBER  ORG DEST STD
BA2321  EMA CPH 20:15
BA2322  EMA OSL 18:30
BA2323  SVG EMA 8:00
BA2324  ENZ LEJ 19:25
BA2325  ENZ EMA 20:00
BA2326  ENZ BGO 08:00
BA2327  ENZ OSL 6:05
```

Comment: You'll need to give a clearer example of what you want to accomplish. Copy paste your data (or dummy data) from your worksheet into your question, then format it to show up as code in your question so we can clearly see what your layout is. Then show us specific examples of what you want to change based on what is in your data.

Comment: You can use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,INDEX!$B:$D,COLUMN(A$2),0),"")`. Enter it in `B2` DATA sheet then drag left and down.

Comment: ah thanks!, this works. makes it a lot easier. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to insert a VLOOKUP function into each of the 3 cells that you want the data to appear in on the INDEX worksheet.

Starting with cell INDEX C1 -
 =VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num)

lookup_value = INDEX!$B$3 (this is the location of the specific number e.g 2993)

table_array = DATA!$A$1:$D$4 (Your data on the DATA worksheet creates a table array)

col_index_num = 2 (you want to pull the data from the second column of the table array)

Your formula in cell C1 should look as below

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX!$B$1,DATA!$A$1:$D$4,2)
```

The formula in cell D1 will be the same but the column index number will now be 3 and so on.

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX!$B$1,DATA!$A$1:$D$4,3)
```